# Chrome shows truncated object prototype name

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am using a factory pattern to create different types of similar objects, say , `Car`, and `Truck`.

When I run something like:

```
var newObj = new this.Vehicles[type] // type can be 'Car' or 'Truck'
console.log(newObj)
/// ...
var newCar = new ObjectFactory('Car', 'ford')
var newTruck = new ObjectFactory('Truck', 'cat')
```

All works fine, but I see this in the console for `console.log`:

```
O…y.V…s.Car {type: "Car"}
O…y.V…s.Truck {type: "Truck"}
```

Where full objects should be shown as `ObjectFactory.Vehicles.Car` and `ObjectFactory.Vehicles.Truck`.
Can I make these be shown as full names instead of dotted and truncated?

Comment: We can't help you with code we cannot see. What does `ObjectFactory` look like?! How are the types on `this.Vehicles` populated?

Comment: It's not about how the code looks but how the browser represents nested objects hierarchy. 

In Firefox it shows these as 
`Object { type: "Car" }` and 
`Object { type: "Truck" }`.

In Safari:
`Car { type: "Car" }` and 
`Truck { type: "Truck" }`

Comment: Which is determined, in part, by how the code looks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different browser consoles work different ways, but ones that show you a type name that isn't a built-in type (like Chrome's) are usually showing you the name (true name or inferred) of the constructor function that created the object. That is:

```
function Foo() {
}
console.log(new Foo);
```

gives us

```
Foo { }
```

...on Chrome.

I'm going to guess (because inexplicably you seem unwilling to tell us) that you have something like this:

```
var ObjectFactory = {
    Vehicles: {
        Car: function() {
        }
    }
};
```

In Chrome, for both

```
console.log(new ObjectFactory.Vehicle.Car);
```

and

```
var c = ObjectFactory.Vehicle.Car;
console.log(new c);
```

...I get the same thing you get:

```
O…y.V…s.Car {}
```

Chrome is inferring a name for the function (at least for debugging purposes), but then eliding that name for display.

As far as I can tell, the only way to override that is to give Chrome a true name to work with:

```
var ObjectFactory = {
    Vehicles: {
        Car: function ObjectFactory$Vehicles$Car() {
        // -----------^
        }
    }
};
```

Now, for both

```
console.log(new ObjectFactory.Vehicle.Car);
```

and

```
var c = ObjectFactory.Vehicle.Car;
console.log(new c);
```

...I get

```
ObjectFactory$Vehicles$Car {}
```

Apparently, Chrome is happy to elide its inferred name, but doesn't elide the proper name you give the function.

It's not quite the name you wanted, but it's a lot clearer than `O…y.V…s.Car`. Sadly, Firefox still says `Object`, but perhaps that will change in time.

Side note: As of ES2015, the way a function's true name is determined was expanded to cover many more cases, such as calling this function `Foo` even though we use an anonymous function expression to create it:

```
var Foo = function() {
};
```

This is defined by the [`SetFunctionName`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-setfunctionname) spec operation and the dozens of places it's called. It's not clear to me, though, that you would want the result once browsers come fully into spec, as I *think* the name of your function would be just `Car`, not `ObjectFactory.Vehicles.Car`.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer!